# Trying to read a file line by line in C but the while loop never terminates

Tags: c

My class requires me to write an operating system simulator in C. The first project was to read in two files, a config file and a metadata file. My first attempt at running the finished code led to a segmentation fault (which I believe I solved). Now I'm having an issue with my fgets statement reading line by line. It's reading every line, but it never stops reading lines. It reads through the file indefinitely until I end the process. I put a printf statement in the while loop so I can see what it's reading, and it does go through each line.

```
int readCfgFile (char *filename, CONFIG *filedata)
{
    char buffer[255], trash[255];
    FILE *cfgfile = malloc(sizeof cfgfile);
    cfgfile = fopen(filename, "r"); // Assumed where segfault was
    if(!cfgfile)
    {
        return -2; // Error opening file
    }
    char *schedulingCode = malloc(8);
    char *logToCode = malloc(200);
    char *tempLine; // Suggested to me as a fix (the using a separate variable part)
    fgets(trash, 255, cfgfile); //Trash the first line of the file
    tempLine = fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile);
    while(tempLine != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(buffer, "Version/Phase: %d", &filedata->version);
        sscanf(buffer, "File Path: %s", filedata->metaPath);
        sscanf(buffer, "CPU Scheduling Code: %s", schedulingCode);
        sscanf(buffer, "Quantum Time (cycles): %d", &filedata->quantum);
        sscanf(buffer, "Memory Available (KB): %d", &filedata->memory);
        sscanf(buffer, "Processor Cycle Time (msec): %d", &filedata->processTime);
        sscanf(buffer, "I/O Cycle Time (msec): %d", &filedata->ioTime);
        sscanf(buffer, "Log To: %s", logToCode);
        sscanf(buffer, "Log File Path: %s", filedata->logPath);
        tempLine = fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile);
        if(tempLine == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
```

The file looks like this:

```
Start Simulator Configuration File
Version/Phase: 1.0
File Path: Test_3.mdf
CPU Scheduling Code: NONE
Quantum Time (cycles): 55
Memory Available (KB): 667
Processor Cycle Time (msec): 10
I/O Cycle Time (msec): 20
Log To: Monitor
Log File Path: logfile_1.lgf
End Simulator Configuration File.
```

Does anyone have any idea why the while loop keeps going on forever?

Comment: `char *logToCode = malloc(sizeof logToCode);` --> `char *logToCode = malloc(200);`, `if(buffer == NULL)` --> `if(tempLine == NULL)`, `char *schedulingCode = malloc(sizeof schedulingCode);` --> `char *schedulingCode = malloc(8);`, `char *tempLine = malloc(sizeof tempLine);` --> `char *tempLine;`, `FILE *cfgfile = malloc(sizeof cfgfile);` --> `FILE *cfgfile;`

Comment: Updated with those suggestions, still doesn't stop. I probably should mention I'm compiling and running the code on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows if that matters. Not allocating the size of the file pointer causes the segmentation fault. Well at least I know where that issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the loop runs forever do you keep getting some output for the statement **printf("%s\n", buffer);** just before the loop termination. Is so what's being printed?

I'd suggest to test the loop logic independent of sscanf code. Following block should work as such (do not need extra check etc.)

```
fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile);  // just to skip the first line
while( (tempLine = fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile)) != NULL)
{
      // all the scanfs to read from tempLine/buffer
      ..
}
```

With that in place you may want to add in your sscanfs and progressively go from there. Some minor comments around **FILE *cfgfile = malloc(sizeof cfgfile);**. This is not required because the call to fopen will return a pointer to FILE and you'll end up leaking the malloc'd cfgfile. Also not sure if this is the complete code or not but logToCode and schedulingCode will also end up getting leaked.

Comment: If I don't malloc the file pointer it segfaults. The output is literally the file over and over again line by line.
However it looks like your suggested while edit worked. Now it segfaults again but that's probably because of how it reads the metadata file.

Comment: @KeithLara - Do you know that `fopen(filename, "r")` returns a `FILE *`? When you added the `malloc()` the behavior changes because you have undefined behavior somewhere, not posted here. Undefined behavior is just that, it behaves differently. I bet it will behave differently just by adding `int a=1`. The `malloc()` you added, which is completely and utterly unnecessary, didn't fix anything. When writing a code, don't just keep guessing. You'll shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Note that you *really need* an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions like this... Also, *do not* update your question to change the code; this changes the question, which renders all previous answers to it invalid. If you're going to ask a new question, *ask it as a new question!*

---

```
char *tempLine = malloc(sizeof tempLine); // Suggested to me as a fix
```

I don't trust that fix. Why allocate a block of memory pointing at a `char`, that has the size of a `char *`? How unusual... There are several other variables in your code that are initialised like this, and it seems like guess-work. Your guess-work is likely causing problems.

`tempLine = fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile);` then overwrites the pointer to that allocation with `buffer` or `NULL`, which results in a memory leak. Whoever suggested that fix to you needs to learn about valgrind (as do you).

Nonetheless, if you ever wish to *trash* a line of input, that'd be better achieved without an intermediate *buffer* like so:

```
fscanf(cfgfile, "%*[^\n]");
fgetc(cfgfile);
```

I'm curious, why is it you appear to be using `%d` to read floating point data?

```
sscanf(buffer, "Version/Phase: %d", ... // Version/Phase: 1.0
```

If only I could see the type of `filedata->version`, I might be able to verify this as an error...

You claimed to have updated this code, yet I can't see the update:

```
tempLine = fgets(buffer, 255, cfgfile);
if(buffer == NULL) // Even checking to see if buffer was null doesn't work
```

There's an error here, and to identify it, I want you to show me how `fgets` could assign `buffer = NULL;` like you seem to expect, in this testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *fgets_fake(char *b, int b_length, FILE *f) {
    /* INSERT CODE HERE! */
    /* Show me how `fgets` can assign `buffer = NULL;` here */
    return b;
}
int main(void) {
    char *buffer = "HELLO WORLD!";
    fgets_fake(buffer, 0, 0);
    printf("Is buffer NULL? %s\n", b ? "no" : "yes");
}
```

You probably meant `if (tempLine == NULL)`, since *that can be reassigned* (following the return).

Comment: I didn't change the question, the segfault was my original issue but I found the answer before asking this question. I updated the source code on my pc, not yet here. Part of the assignment was to save the version type as an int, I don't know why. Valgrind doesn't work on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. "tempLine == NULL" doesn't solve it.

Comment: You most likely had a stale binary, caused by a failed compilation or mistaken identity.